# Compile ffmpeg-4.2.2 on macOS with Haivision-SRT 1.4.1 >>> ERROR: srt >= 1.3.0 not found using pkg-config

Tags: macos, ffmpeg, streaming, compile

I got following error while compiling ffmpeg-4.2.2 on MacOS 10.14.6 with the Haivision-SRT 1.4.1 package:

```
ERROR: srt >= 1.3.0 not found using pkg-config
```

First, I tried it with the srt package from Homebrew and then I compiled it from source. But both times I got the same error.
I compiled the same ffmpeg 4.2.2 package on Ubuntu with SRT 1.4.1 without problems.

From the `ffbuild/config.log`:

```
require_pkg_config libsrt srt >= 1.3.0 srt/srt.h srt_socket  
check_pkg_config libsrt srt >= 1.3.0 srt/srt.h srt_socket  
test_pkg_config libsrt srt >= 1.3.0 srt/srt.h srt_socket  
false --exists --print-errors srt >= 1.3.0  
ERROR: srt >= 1.3.0 not found using pkg-config
```

Why is it asking for such an old libsrt version?
From where does it get this requirement?

Comment: "From where does it get this requirement?" The `configure` file has a requirement for libsrt 1.3.0 or greater. Are you compiling ffmpeg via a homebrew formula?

Comment: I followed these instructions https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/macOS >> _Compiling FFmpeg yourself_ and only installed some dependencies with Homebrew.

Comment: `enabled libsrt            && require_pkg_config libsrt "srt >= 1.3.0" srt/srt.h srt_socket` >> the configure file on Ubuntu has the same line but compiled without errors the 1.4.1 srt package. Does ffmpeg really require this old package or is it a bug?

Comment: ffmpeg requires that it **not** be old.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official homebrew recipe does not support libsrt among some other stuff too.

Try the [homebrew-ffmpeg](https://github.com/homebrew-ffmpeg/homebrew-ffmpeg) tap:

```
brew tap homebrew-ffmpeg/ffmpeg
brew install homebrew-ffmpeg/ffmpeg/ffmpeg --with-srt
```

You can see additional supported options with:

```
brew options homebrew-ffmpeg/ffmpeg/ffmpeg
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't understand that tap message as I tried it with homebrew. Thank you. Great. I thought all options are gone and I have to compile it myself :-)